# Abrir arquivo CSV e ler seu conteúdo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Eu tenho a informação do arquivo CSV no `console.log` do back-end, eu precisaria acessar esse arquivo e ler seu conteúdo, alguma dica?

Esse é o trecho de código do back-end que recebe o arquivo:

```
exports.anexo = function(req, res){

  var arquivo = req.files.uploads;
  var date = new Date();
  var dateTime = date.getTime();
  console.log(arquivo);

  var fileList = [];
    if(arquivo != undefined){
        for(var i=0; i < arquivo.length; i++){
            if(arquivo[i].originalFilename != undefined){
                var url_arquivo = dateTime + '_' + arquivo[i].originalFilename;
                var tipo_arquivo = arquivo[i].type;
                var path_origem = arquivo[i].path;
                var path_destino = './uploads/' + url_arquivo;

                var File = {
                    url_arquivo: url_arquivo
                };

                fileList.push(File);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E aqui tá a parte do código no front-end que lê o arquivo e manda pro back-end

```
anexaArquivos(fileList : File[]) : Promise<any> {
    console.log('chamou a função no regiao.service')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject ) => {
      let formData : FormData = new FormData()
      let xhr : XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()

      if(fileList.length > 0){
        for( let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
          formData.append("uploads[]", fileList[i], fileList[i].name);
        }
      }
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
              if (xhr.status === 200) {
                  resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response))
              } else {
                  reject(xhr.response)
              }
          }
      }

      xhr.open('POST', `${SES_API}/regiao/importar`, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.userService.sessao.accessToken}`);
      xhr.send(formData);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma parada chamada D3.js que serve pra te ajudar a usar dados, você pode usar ele é adicionando:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

(aqui está o link do github com informações sobre o d3 https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki)

Essa é uma maneira bem fácil, colocando a linha do `src` acima depois é só você usar:

```
d3.csv(arquivo,funcao)
```

Onde arquivo é o nome do arquivo com final .csv e função é uma função que você irá criar onde executará o que você quer.

Comment: Você colocou um link para um livro em PDF, além do link ser inválido, não é permitido distribuição de material dessa forma no site, a não ser que o material seja de livre distribuição. Se o livro não estiver disponível gratuitamente pelo autor ou editora, trata-se de pirataria e não é permitido no site.

Comment: Eu resolvi com o FileReader e ReadAsText, mas vou pesquisar sobre o D3, valeu!!